# Financial function YIELD takes too long to complete

Tags: php, excel, excel-formula, phpexcel

Treasury Yield Function isn't available in PHPEXCEL. I've developed, as per Microsoft instruction, this function but, unfortunately, it takes too long to give actual output results for more than 12 digits. How can I resolve this slowness issue for above 12 digits?

```
$mdate = '15/11/2016'; $sdate= '15/02/2008'; $cr = 5.75; //8.59%

$price = 102.662233775443

$objPHPExcel->YIELD($sdate,$mdate,($cr/100),$price,100,2,1);
```

Comment: Why have you written a YIELD function that's called directly against a Workbook object rather than within the calculation engine for Excel formulae?

Comment: And if you do expect help in improving the performance of your function, then it helps if you post the code for your function rather than simply showing where you call it

Comment: Actually I have developed a Treasury software by using php. So I needed some functions like price, yield, forecast etc..

Comment: phpexcel library helped me so much but unfortunately yield function isn't available in this library. Up to 10 digits for Price it gives good response but more than 10 digits it takes 3 second. Whereas Microsoft Excel gives the same result within one second. Thank you.

Comment: Finally I have gotten actual results corresponding with MS Excel. I want to contribute this function in phpexcel classes..

Comment: Rather than contribute to PHPExcel, which is no longer supported, consider submitting a PR to its successor [PHPSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) instead